# Developing plug-ins using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I am currently trying to get started with developing / using OSGi bundles using eclipse. The problem is that the combination eclipse / OSGi is really hard to set up and seems to be very heavy-weight. I created a simple "Hello World" bundle with an Activator. I try to run it as an "OSGi framework", but I get spammed by errors / exceptions. First I get a lot of theses errors:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2015-04-18 15:03:31.119
!MESSAGE Could not install bundle plugins/org.eclipse.team.core_3.7.0.v20130514-1224.jar   A bundle is already installed with the name "org.eclipse.team.core" and version "3.7.0.v20130514-1224"
```

I get this for every bundle that ships with eclipse. After that I get the following exception:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
```

After that I get an exception related to jetty (why?)

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.
Caused by: org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: default : Permission denied
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

That seems a lot of trouble for getting a program to print "Hello World". Does anyone know how to set up eclipse for plug-in projects?

Comment: Are you trying to make an eclipse plugin ?? If so You can run it as eclipse application Right click> Debug as > eclipse application instead of osgi

Comment: No, just a plain plugin.

Comment: It looks like you create an eclipse hello world plug-in so i think you should run it as eclipse application and everything will be right

Comment: It does look like you are using things that only work in an Eclipse plugin rather than an OSGi only plugin.

Comment: Well, I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as it turns out eclipse is a bit sloppy when it comes to creating a new project. In Juno you can either create a "Plug-in Project" or a "Plug-in Development > Plug-in Project". The first is an eclipse plugin, the latter is an ordinary OSGi bundle. This is really unfortunately named.

I created a new OSGi bundle project, a new "OSGi Framework" configuration and added the essentials:

```
org.apache.felix.gogo.command
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
org.eclipse.osgi.console
```

and my own bundle (`com.vogella.osgi.firstbundle`) to the Bundles. Now everything works fine, the thread starts and prints to the console and I can enter commands like `ss` / `start` etc.